# Intellisense error / including additional libraries with environment variables

Tags: visual-studio-2010, environment-variables, intellisense

I'm working on a C++ project (VS 2010) using CPLEX.

I have included the required cplex libraries in the project settings as follows:

- added the "additional include directories" under C/C++ > general
- added the "additional library directories" under linker > general
- added the .lib files as "additional dependecies" under linker > input

Everything compiles fine, however my problem is that intellisense still reports errors (red squiggly underlines) such as "cannot open source file" in the #include line, and "identifier undefined" when using variable types defined in the CPLEX library.

The only difference with other projects that don't have this behaviour is that this time I have used windows environment variables in setting the include path, i.e. the library directories and include directories are defined similar to: `%CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR%\cplex\include`

I have set it like this so that I can build this project on different machines without messing around in the project properties. Since CPLEX is installed separately, using relative paths to specify additional directories is not really an option.

I'd like to repeat that the project compiles, it's only the intellisense errors that are bothering me.

I know I can turn off the intellisense error reporting, but if someone has a workaround for this I'd love to hear about it.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 3):

This problem is known to Microsoft:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779874/intellisense-cant-handle-using-environemt-variable-in-include-path

The only way I know of to avoid it is to manually enter the full literal path. The bug is marked "deferred" which I think means Microsoft has regarded it not serious enough to be fixed soon.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to replace `%CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR%\cplex\include` with `$(CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR)\cplex\include`. This is the syntax Visual Studio uses for its built-in variables such as `$(VCInstallDir)`, but it also works for environment variables (so long as they don't have the same name as a built-in variable) and is recognised by intellisense as well as the compiler.

(I realise this is an old question, but it ranks highly in search results so it could help others even if not the original poster.)